# LL vs LR in CFGs

Tags: context-free-grammar

What is the precise definitions for, and difference between, LL and LR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly:

- LR means bottom-up (shift-reduce) parsing.
- LL usually means top-down (recursive descent) parsing.